# Definition of normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, definition, normal-subgroups

One of the equivalent definitions for normal subgroups that I have studied is:

"Let $G$ be a group and let $H \leq G$. We say that $H$ is normal in $G$ if $\forall g \in G$ we have $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$."

Applying the cancellation property of groups, we also have:

$gHg^{-1} \subseteq H \Leftrightarrow gHg^{-1} = H$, as they have the same cardinal.

However, I have been told that:

"Let $G$ be a group, let $H \leq G$ and let $k \in G$. It is not true that $kHk^{-1} \subseteq H \Leftrightarrow kHk^{-1} = H$. However, it is true that $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$ $\forall g\in G$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $gHg^{-1} = H$ $\forall g\in G$."

I don't understand the first claim, reasoning with the cancellation property as above.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on your proposed proof?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are infinite sets with the same cardinality and $X\subseteq Y$, it does not follow that $X=Y$. I think that's the mistake you're making with $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$.

Comment: The first claim states that if we start with a given $k\in G$, then $kHk^{-1}\subseteq H$ $\iff$ $kHk^{-1}=H$. The second claim states that $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ **for all** $g\in G$ is true if and only if $gHg^{-1}=H$ **for all** $g\in G$.

Comment: I have found what was wrong. As Greg Martin said, I was assuming that both sets would be equal if they had the same cardinal. My reasoning only would be true for finite groups, right?

Comment: @Numox: Yes, that's only true in the case where $H$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you, it was very useful :D